# Implementing Webservice on JBoss, maven and choices

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf

I 'm to implement a webservice in JBoss5 running on Java 6. According to the [JBoss Documentation](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws), the choices are either use the JBoss native implementation, CXF or metro. As native would not need any additional libraries (CXF would pull in Spring?) I thought that this would be the first choice.

The WS contract is given in an WSDL, so I want to generate the stubs out of it. But the JBoss tools bark at the WSDL, whereas CXF wsdl2java happily generates sources. Can I use these sources and not depend on CXF but use the native JBoss WS stack? The annotations in the generated classes even point to javax stuff (which could be a 4. choice, as I can create a WS with java 6 without additional dependencies?)

How do I configure the webservice? Do I still need a web.xml to define some servlet? What maven dependencies do I need?

Sorry for all this apparently silly questions, but I did a lot of searching and reading but the more I read the more confused I 'm. JBoss documentation is either all about stating with java beans and annotations and / or ant, the public jboss maven repo is a mess (some WS stuff is under jboss, other under org.jboss.jbossws and even other artefacts under org.jboss.ws ..)

Any pointer to howtos and or documentation is greatly welcome.

Comment: While you are not EAP, this documentation could still help 

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with CXF, running a self contained war, and just treat jboss as a servlet container, and completely ignore all the web services gunk that jboss tries to provide.

Then you just follow the regular CXF directions for a wsdl first service, and end up with a nice clean portable .war file.  It will/should run in jboss (jboss might try and provide some extra libraries itself, but you should be able to set some sort of classloader containment policy to make sure it loads from the context first, not from jboss firstt.

This gives you

1. nice clean wsdl first development
2. one simple set of instructions to follow (just cxf)
3. maven repos that make sense
4. Still using jboss, because someone thought that was a good idea.

Using the java 6 standard webservices is an option, depends what else you want to use in your app.  I was already going to use spring, and CXF's spring integration is tidier and better maintained than the jaxws-commons spring portions.  Also, maven tools for generating from the wsdl are more convoluted and less maintained if you go with the stock jaxws-ri.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Somehow i forgot about that question. At the time of writing i was really annoyed that such rather simple task was that hard to set up in JBoss. Good to hear that others share my view on JBoss ;)  We settled the issue using XCF (as you suggest) but my colleague opted for XCF-JBoss stack. Thanks for your answer.